# JFace ComboViewer resizes itself when the main composite is maximized/minimized

Tags: java, combobox, swt, jface, composite

In a JFace wizard I have a main composite and a ComboViewer within that composite. First time when I open the window I can see the ComboViewer in a proper size within its parent composite, then when I resize the JFace wizard (through clicking the maximize option on the window) ComboViewer does adjust itself to the size of the window and then I close the window without minimizing it back. Everything is fine until this point. 
But when I reopen the wizard I see that the ComboViewer resizes itself to a very very very small widget which could hardly be seen, this strange behaviour happens only through this workflow -

1) Open the wizard.
2) Maximize the window and close the wizard.
3) Reopen the wizard and you see that the ComboViewer resizes itself and
   displays as an extremely small widget.
4) Again you maximize/minimize the main window then the ComboViewer draws itself 
   to the original intended size.

**[PLEASE NOTE - This strange behaviour happens only with SWT 3.7, I tried resetting my target platform in Eclipse with SWT 3.5 and the ComboViewer behaved absolutely perfect under all the circumstances, only with SWT 3.7 I was able to reproduce this issue consistently]**

Here's my code for the ComboViewer, it's just a normal code -

```
final Composite c = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

//layout for the composite
GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().extendedMargins(0, 0, 0,5).numColumns(3).applyTo(c);

ComboViewer selectViewer = new ComboViewer(c);
selectViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
selectViewer.setLabelProvider(new CustomLabelProvider())
selectViewer.setComparator(new CustomComparator());
selectViewer.getCombo().setVisibleItemCount(15);
```

I tried searching through Eclipse community forums to check if there was a known Bug logged for this issue only with SWT 3.7, or to check if anyone else has figured out this issue and if it's a typical issue with SWT 3.7 but could not find any relevant info on the Internet.

Can someone please tell me if this issue is already known and there's nothing that can be done about it in the production code unless the next release of SWT or something? or if there's a workaround for this issue that has already been figured out?

Comment: The current release of SWT is 4.5 - http://eclipse.org/swt/

Comment: Yes I agree, I do not have much of a hold on changing my Application code to be compatible with SWT 4.5 for now. I wanted to know if this ComboViewer issue was a known fact with SWT 3.7?

Comment: Have you set a layout on your Composite `c`? You should set layouts on all Composites.

Comment: Initially I thought not setting layouts could be the issue but I tried setting them too on my composite but still the ComboViewer behaves in a similar manner..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue long ago but missed out on updating this post.

We need to explicitly call the layout method to force a lay out of all widgets that are in the parent hierarchy of the changed control (in my case the control is the comboviewer) up to and including the receiver.

```
this.layout(new Control[] { comboViewer.getCombo() });
```